# Usage of 「V+見込みです」

Tags: grammar, syntax

I want to understand the usage for ’V＋見込みです’。I want to say something is expected to get delayed, so which is better 「～が遅れる見込みです」or　「～が遅れてしまう見込みです」.I have added しまうfor an expression of disappointment, is it incorrect in this context?

Answer (score 2):

> 「Verb in て-Form + **しまう** + 見込{みこ}みです」

While I would not consider this expression incorrect per se, I know for certain that it would be far less common than:

> 「Verb in Dictionary Form + 見込{みこ}みです」 used in conjunction with a phrase expressing disappointment.

You could say, for instance:

「残念{ざんねん}ですが、電車{でんしゃ}が遅{おく}れる見込みです。」 or

「電車が遅れる見込みだと聞{き}いて残念です。」

If you ***must***, however, use 「しまう」 for some reason and still want to sound perfectly natural, you could use it by changing 「見込みです」 to 「可能性{かのうせい}があります」.  I know this might not be what you wanted to know, but for future reference, I added it.

> 「電車が遅れて**しまう**可能性があります。」

Answer (score 1):

～が遅れる見込みです is more natural than ～が遅れてしまう見込みです but ～が遅れる見込みです doesn't imply speaker's disappointment.

I feel ～が遅れてしまう見込みです is a bit unnatural. I feel 見込み means objective expectation, so to add someone's emotion to it may not be appropriate.

If you want to add your disappointment to it, ～が遅れてしまうみたいです(ようです) would be natural.